# Using formula in a new column of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro that will insert a new column into a table, enter a formula in the first cell after the header, and paste it to all cells in that column to the bottom of the table.

My issue is defining the bottom of the table. I can find the last row with data by using the following.

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

And the formula portion will always start in this column and works for the first cell:

```
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]=R[-1]C[-1]"
Range("E2").Select
```

Here is the issue; ideally I'd want the range to start at "E1" (or Selection since its already there) and end at the variable # of rows the table ends at, NOT E10.

```
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, "E10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I've tried replacing "E10" with just the LastRow variable but I see that wont work since it's just a number. Any help would be appreciated!

(I've also tried this range, but since its a new column there's no way Excel knows where the bottom of the table is with ctrl shift down; maybe it can be tweaked/altered to work?):

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: You're not using a table, you're using a range. Maybe look at using an Excel Table object, which will automaticlly apply formulas to all its rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("E2").Resize(LastRow - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]=R[-1]C[-1]"
```

You don't have to Select - just change the FormulaR1C1 property of the whole range. The -1 part of the Resize argument is because you are in row 2. If you started in row 10, it would be `LastRow - 9`.